# How to merge HDFS small files into a one large file?

Tags: bash, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have number of small files generated from Kafka stream so I like merge small files to one single file but this merge is based on the date i.e. the original folder may have number of previous files but I only like to merge for given date files to one single file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like the code below to iterate over the smaller files and aggregate them into a big one (assuming that `source` contains the HDFS path to your smaller files, and `target` is the path where you want your big result file):

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.listStatus(new Path(source)).map(_.getPath.toUri.getPath).
foreach(name => spark.read.text(name).coalesce(1).write.mode(Append).text(target))
```

This example assumes text file format, but you can just as well read any Spark-supported format, and you can use different formats for source and target, as well

Comment: So, this is the 1st time I have seen this solution. Absolutely sure? I will try it later

Comment: @thebluephantom I've used it pretty much unchanged in my project (only added `coalesce(1)` to force producing one physical file - my own use case only called for one possibly-distributed HDFS location). It's fairly slow, though I'm not aware of a faster approach

Comment: Good stuff. Guess you neec to remove the small files.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Looks like I need to filter out the files based on lastModified since I only need files which are between date range.

Comment: coalesce(1) means it will do merge on one core? so will it take too long?

Comment: The whole process is already sequential because of `foreach`, so `coalesce(1)` shouldn't really slow it down much more - in theory, anyways

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use `.repartition(1)` to write all results to 1 file. if you need to split by date, consider `partitionBy("your_date_value")` .

if you're working within HDFS and S3, this may also be helpful. you might actually even use `s3-dist-cp` and stay within HDFS.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/seven-tips-for-using-s3distcp-on-amazon-emr-to-move-data-efficiently-between-hdfs-and-amazon-s3/#5

There's a specific option to aggregate multiple files in HDFS using a --groupBy option based n a regular expression pattern. So if the date is in the file name, you can group based on that pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I can not add +1 since my reputation is below 15.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop a spark application. Using this application read the data from small files and create `dataframe` and write `dataframe` to big file in append mode.

Comment: See above answer.

Comment: My approach is generic in which you can select specific file for particular date and write it.